# Creating a mean square error function

Tags: matlab

I'm really new to MATLAB and have to implement some functions. To start, I'm supposed to make a function about a mean square error, for which I have the following formula:

[image: formula]

My goal is to implement this in MATLAB. I've tried to analyse this for days, but I'm still lost. I guess the first thing to do is to create a function and then put all of the calculations. Should I declare variables like N though? Or can I just use them in the calculations without declaring? I'm just looking for some advises that would help me get started, I have no one else to ask about this, so a short guide/tips on how to take down this particular example would be amazing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not the place to start learning programming.

Comment: Nice. I've seen a variety of questions on Stack. It's supposed to be a helping forum, as far as I'm concerned, and I'm almost afraid to ask about something, cause people here are so well educated that they can't help someone who tries to learn the basics. I'd say there are no 'wrong' questions, and instead of closing my question, it would be better to actually point out how could I change it so it would fit Stack's standards.

Comment: @Pauline You're mistaken; Stack Overflow is not a forum. To find out more, check out the [Site Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page. As far as your question's topicality goes; it's too broad according to Stack Overflow guidelines, and asking for external guides/resources for how to do something. Stack Overflow is a site for specific programming questions you have about solving specific programming problems, typically about code that already exists. Questions asking "how can I make this thing in X language" are usually too broad.

Comment: @Pauline read [ask]. If you have a basic question, first prove that you have tried to solve it yourself by posting some code and telling us what went wrong with it. Posting bad code is fine. Asking for code where you have shown no effort of solving it yourself is definitely off topic.

Comment: Alright, that I can work with. Still, it's a place to get some answers, right? I don't have any problems with changing the way I ask questions, correcting my ways of using Stack. It just makes me mad when people are hostile and lower your reputation or whatever instead, like you, which I appreciate, trying to communicate.

Comment: @Dan if it's definitely off-topic, why answer at all?

Comment: @Adriaan I just did. Normally I wouldn't but today I happened to. There is no harm in it, no rules against answering bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a mean square error you need two inputs, `Y` and `Y_bar` and one output `E`. You don't need to declare `N` because it is implied by the length of each of your inputs. I'm going to assume that your inputs are both column vectors and are the same length.

```
function E = MSE(Y, Y_bar)

    N = size(Y,1);
    E = sum((Y-Y_bar).^2)/N

end
```

You should save this code a an .m file named mse.m and make sure it is in your working directory. If you don't know what that means, you need to look it up.

This is extremely basic MATLAB though, before you continue with anything, I think you should start by working through some beginners guides. As mentioned, stackoverflow is not the place to learn the very basics of a programming language.

Comment: thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for. I've read a beginners guide but wanted to see how this works out in a specific example, cause I'm still having problems trying to learn it. Now it's clearer though. Thanks!

Comment: @Pauline next time you ask a question, make sure you post some code.

Comment: or `E = mean((Y-Y_bar).^2)`